# Installation of v5.50 gives me an immediate Bootstrap exception

Tags: upgrade

I have just done an upgrade to v5.50 and get an immediate:

`RuntimeException: CiviCRM has not bootstrapped sufficiently to fire event "hook_civicrm_entityTypes". in Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch() (line 190 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php).`

I have a script that does the refresh of a new version and I'm not aware of anything I have changed on my UAT server where I test these things. Has anyone else seen this?

Running on D7 v7.88

Comment: I have this problem too. Any news?

Comment: I cannot seem to find anything on it - I noticed that the release has had a minor tweak to 5.50.1 due to an API regression but it does not like it relates to this issue.  Just tried an install and get the same issue

Comment: Does the backtrace have more information? Can you double-check if the Extension upgrades have run? (go to the civicrm/admin/extensions page, it will show a notification, or run "cv api extension.upgrade" on the command line)

Comment: @bgm The error sends the site in critical error, thus it doesn't respond to any command, nor cv works. I have Wordpress 6.0.0 and am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @Ferdi2005 Can you locate the "wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog" directory on your server, and look at the recently modified files (open with a plain text editor). It might have more details about the error.

Comment: @bgm I don't think there's nothing unusual in it: https://gist.github.com/ferdi2005/5df74827d3dc860d2f4d38016ce645e5

Comment: Besides, I'd like to add that the problem arises only after a database migration.

Comment: Only happens with civicrm_entity module? Also happens on wordpress. I can get cv/drush/drupal to work by commenting out the call in Hook.php

Comment: I can see that Container.php had commonModuleBuildList added on 21/4/2022 in the git change log.

Comment: Commenting out the line adding commonBuildModuleList in Container.php does appear to solve the issue for me, so that might be a temporary workaround.

Comment: There is a related issue opened at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3496 and a discussion opened at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/1izo73dcpjfcbem97eek7s6d6w

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check that there are no missing extensions on the system. You may need to apply the patch below or comment out commonMoudleBuildList in Container.php to see the list of missing extensions.

A patch is available https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/91e1627497d53cba04c6919575efb7061daf125a.patch
that makes the load order predictable. This patch will enable the list of missing extensions to be displayed.

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23716
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23268
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3496

Answer (score 1):

I have just run my upgrade script against v5.50.3 and all went well, so I think we are OK on this now.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue since a long time on D8 and D9, I ended up not using CiviCRM entity after a very painful removal.

Now I see this issue on another site that had been upgraded to 5.50.1
This time I do not want to remove CiviCRM entity. But, sorry, I have no clue  how to put CiviCRM entity back on track.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out commonModuleBuildList in Container.php solves the problem in the short term.

From the git log I see that Container.php had commonModuleBuildList added on 21/4/2022.

Creating a patch in composer that comments out the line maintains git workflow.

The next question is how to get initialize() to be called later. I had the idea to use *hook_event_dispatcher*, although it does not work. The fix seems to solve *civicrm_entity* but then block/user and the core drupal CiviCRM module also has hooks that are not supported by the event dispatcher.

Comment: Thanks - I think this is not a general solution for admins that just keep their systems patched and updated.  Let's see if there is a more general fix.

Answer (score 0):

There is another patch available related with this kind of error https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23739